# How to add layout rules in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using [this](https://github.com/helloJp/Sticker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/jp/sticker/MainActivity.java) library for adding sticker on captured image.

The problem is that, this library is using `Relative Layout`. I need to convert this to constraint layout, but once i do this, it stops working.

This is what it does when user adds an sticker on `image view`

```
StickerView stickerView = new StickerView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.image);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.image);
    ((ViewGroup) mImageView.getParent()).addView(stickerView, params);
```

When i convert this layout to `constraint layout` I wrote this.

```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

but there is not `params.addRule` function for constraint layout, and i am unable to understand how to add an element over constraint layout from code.

Constraint Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_photo_editor">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effect_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/grayCheckout"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#90000000"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The parent is a ConstraintLayout? else you can't add another Params

Comment: Yes I have set parent layout to constraint,

Comment: You need to add the layout xml (or code) so we can help

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos : I have added the xml, every time user taps on sticker i need to add it on constraint layout. Sticker is coming from list view

Answer (score 1):

To place `ConstraintLayout` views programmatically, you will need to use [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html).

> This class allows you to define programmatically a set of constraints to be used with ConstraintLayout. It lets you create and save constraints, and apply them to an existing ConstraintLayout.

There are some good tutorials online that explain how to use this facility. Just search for `ConstraintSet`.